# How to set State Array variable for form Data

Tags: reactjs

I have an Form Data input in react js application. I have tried below code to set Form Data

```
 this.state = {
      checked: true,
     
  formData:{ 
    emp_location:[],
    emp_designation:"",
    items:[],
  },
  
 
};
```

So i want to set

```
onSelect(selectedList) {
 
  this.setState({
    items: selectedList
 
  });
```

But it's not working.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this

```
onSelect(selectedList) {
 
  this.setState({
    formData: {...this.state.formData, items: selectedList}
 
  });
```

Hopefuly it works :)